# Filebrowser to hide extension in Vb6

Tags: file, vb6

I am making a VB6 software that will load some Flash files from the **App.Path & "/" & folder** and since I have a lot of Files to load , I figured that the windows FileListBox would be best since I just have to add a mouse click event.
My Problem comes in that the File Browser shows the .swf extension which I dont like. Is there a way I can hide the extension?

Comment: You should really be looking in `App.Path & "\" & Folder` (not `"/"`)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing too special about the `FileListBox` so why not just use a regular `ListBox` and populate it yourself without the extensions?

You could even use the `FileListBox` (with `Visible = False`) to generate the list of files for you in the location specified and copy this list to your `ListBox`